# Using lambda to execute a void: Is this correct?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Is what I am doing correct? I basically want to execute a certain void method.

```
public abstract class Uniforms {
    public static void setUniformMatrix4(final UniformLocation uniformLocation, final boolean transpose, final Matrix4f matrix4f) {
        setUniformImpl(uniformLocation, u -> GL20.glUniformMatrix4(uniformLocation.getLocation(), transpose, matrix4f.asFloatBuffer()));
    }

    public static void setUniformMatrix4(final UniformLocation uniformLocation, final boolean transpose, final FloatBuffer matrix4fFloatBuffer) {
        setUniformImpl(uniformLocation, u -> GL20.glUniformMatrix4(uniformLocation.getLocation(), transpose, matrix4fFloatBuffer));
    }

    public static void setUniform(final UniformLocation uniformLocation, final float value) {
        setUniformImpl(uniformLocation, u -> GL20.glUniform1f(uniformLocation.getLocation(), value));
    }

    public static void setUniform(final UniformLocation uniformLocation, final int value) {
        setUniformImpl(uniformLocation, u -> GL20.glUniform1i(uniformLocation.getLocation(), value));
    }

    private static void setUniformImpl(final UniformLocation uniformLocation, final Consumer<UniformLocation> consumer) {
        Program oldProgram = Program.getUsing();
        for (Program program : Program.getPrograms()) {
            if (program.usesUniform(uniformLocation)) {
                program.use();
                consumer.accept(uniformLocation);
            }
        }
        if (oldProgram != null) {
            oldProgram.use();
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it looks fine, why do you think there is an issue?

Comment: @assylias Because I am not sure if this is how lambdas should be used, a `Consumer<T>` generally consumes a `T`. However in my case the `u` I am passing is not used. I might think I'd need something that consumes nothing and produces nothing?

Comment: @Downvoter: Please clarify why.

Comment: Perhaps the downvote was because it's not clear what your question is. But they should have left a comment. Your previous comment does clarify the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your program compiles and gives the output you are expecting, then in that sense it's correct. It could be clarified somewhat though.

The four public overloads all take a `UniformLocation` parameter which is then passed to the `setUniformImpl` method. This method then calls the consumer and passes to it the `uniformLocation` ... which is then ignored. The calls to `GL2.glUniform*` methods in the lambdas all **capture** `uniformLocation` instead of using the `u` parameter. You could replace the `Consumer` with a `Runnable`.

Alternatively, you could change the type of the `Consumer` to whatever the return value of `Uniform.getLocation()` is and extract each one of those calls into `setUniformImpl` and pass the result as the arg to `consumer.accept`. That would simplify things a bit. You'd end up with something like,

```
public static void setUniform(final UniformLocation uniformLocation, final int value) {
    setUniformImpl(uniformLocation, u -> GL20.glUniform1i(u, value));
}

private static void setUniformImpl(final UniformLocation uniformLocation, final Consumer<Location> consumer) {
    ...
    consumer.accept(uniformLocation.getLocation());
    ...
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the `Runnable` interface aswell, would it be correct to use in this sense? As far as I know it is the only interface in which you can execute 'methods'.

Comment: Sure, `Runnable` will work. The main point is the "shape" of the function, in the sense of the number of arguments and return values. When choosing a functional interface, first look at the number of arguments and return values, and choose the functional interface that matches. (Possibly specialized for primitives or booleans.) `Runnable` takes zero args and returns void, so if that matches what you want, `Runnable` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

If it compiles then there is no issue.

Let's say a method expects:

```
void m(Consumer<SomeEvent> e);
```

Then in Java 7 you could write:

```
m(new Consumer<SomeEvent> () { void accept(SomeEvent e) { /* do nothing */ } });
```

where the consumer you provide ignores the argument `e`.

Similarly, with lambdas, you can ignore the arguments and write:

```
m(e -> { /* do nothing */ });
```